# SharePoint does not exist in the namespace Microsoft

Tags: 2010

this probably isn't the best place to ask but can you help me with this?

It relates to a SharePoint tool which is being developed.

The compiler error is:

> The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have just imported this project from my other desktop where it compiles with 0 errors and 0 warnings.

SharePoint can be easily accessed through the browser and both compilers use SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the 2nd computer does not have SharePoint 2010 (desktop) installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll from the GAC of the sharepoint server to the other machine to compile your project there. Check the reference in your project if it points to your local GAC.